# O correto é "aterrissar" ou "aterrizar"?

Tags: ortografia, português-brasileiro

Nos noticiários de *São Paulo - Brasil* os âncoras quando querem dizer que um avião pousou na pista eles utilizam a palavra "aterrizou", mas aqui no Rio de Janeiro nós falamos a palavra "aterrissou". Ambas são aceitas ou alguém está falando errado?

Comment: Acho que ambas estão corretas, embora no português europeu digamos _aterrar_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas são aceitas, segundo o Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa:

*aterrissar v.*

*aterrizar v.*

Porém não existe "aterrizagem", só "aterrissagem" :)

---

<sub>PS: sou de São Paulo e falo "aterrissar"</sub>

Comment: A forma _aterrizagem_ existe e é dicionarizada: http://www.aulete.com.br/aterrizagem

Comment: Verdade, porém não consta do VOLP.